# django-admin.py makemessages does not create .po files

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

Here I've marked strings for translation, base.html:

```
  <li><a href="{% url 'specific_static_page' 'apie-mus' %}">{% trans 'Apie mus' %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'categories_index' %}">{% trans 'Produktai' %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'news_index' %}">{% trans 'Naujienos' %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'specific_static_page' 'dokumentai' %}">{% trans 'Dokumentai' %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'specific_static_page' 'kontaktai' %}">{% trans 'Kontaktai' %}</a></li>
```

settings.py:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'C:/Users/Marijus/PycharmProjects/legatine/locale',
)
```

and I run the command :

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a
```

It runs without errors or anything, however it doesn't create any .po files. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That command is used to reexamine all the source but to create the po files you must specify the language with

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
```

Being de the language Deutsche

Comment: run 'django-admin.py compilemessages' to compile those messages